# Quais as diferenças entre Kernel e Microkernel?

Tags: terminologia, sistema-operacional, kernel

Estudando sobre sistemas operacionais deparei-me com conceitos sobre *kernel* e *microkernel*. Em minhas pesquisas encontrei as seguintes definições:

**Kernel**

> Em computação, o núcleo ou cerne (*em inglês: **kernel***) é o componente
> central do sistema operativo da maioria dos computadores; ele serve de
> ponte entre aplicativos e o processamento real de dados feito a nível
> de hardware. As responsabilidades do núcleo incluem gerenciar os
> recursos do sistema (a comunicação entre componentes de hardware e
> software).

**Fonte:** [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAcleo_(software))

**Microkernel**

> ***Micronúcleo***, ou ***microkernel***, é uma arquitetura de núcleo (*kernel*) de
> um sistema operativo cujas funcionalidades são quase todas executadas
> fora do núcleo, em oposição a um *núcleo monolítico*. Os processos se
> comunicam com um núcleo mínimo, usando o mínimo possível o "espaço do
> sistema" (*kernel space*). Neste local os aplicativos tem acesso a todas
> as instruções e a todo o hardware e deixando o máximo de recursos
> rodando no "espaço do usuário" (*user space*) em que o software tem
> algumas restrições, não podendo acessar algumas hardwares, nem tem
> acesso a todas as instruções).

**Fonte:** [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micron%C3%BAcleo_(inform%C3%A1tica))

Quais são as principais diferenças entre ambos, na prática? Quais as vantagens / desvantagens entre si?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Definições

**Kernel** é um termo genérico e a definição já está na pergunta. Ele é o núcleo do sistema operacional, é o que faz as coisas básicas que um sistema operacional deve fazer. Não inclui nele as ferramentas auxiliares que costumam estar presentes nos SOs para facilitar o acesso às suas funções.

**Microkernel** é uma tipo específico de *kernel*. Talvez a pergunta seria melhor se fosse a diferença entre um *kernel* monolítico e um *microkernel*.

Enquanto o **monolítico** tenta colocar todas funções principais do sistema operacional dentro do *kernel*, dentro de um processo especial que tem diversos privilégios, o *microkernel* tenta colocar só o necessário e deixar tudo o que não precisa estar no núcleo central como serviços auxiliares em processos diferentes e sem privilégios especiais.

O monolítico costuma ter melhor performance porque faz menos mudanças de contexto. Por ter um acesso privilegiado em muitas funções pode executar de forma mais eficiente.

O micronúcleo (*microkernel*) tende a ser mais confiável e seguro. Uma falha em componentes auxiliares não derruba todo o sistema operacional.

Existem até outras formas, como o [*exokernel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exokernel) ou *nanokernel*, onde o núcleo realmente é mínimo, e todo o resto passa para aplicações comuns.

Também existe o *unikernel* que vai para o lado oposto. Na verdade ele funciona mais como uma biblioteca operacional, já que não tem um espaço de usuário **a** aplicação fica junto do *kernel* e tem o melhor da performance, costuma ser até mais seguro porque permite muito pouco já que só tem o que a aplicação precisa, e não deixa interagir de formas variadas por não ser genérico. Ele só tem o mínimo para dar acesso ao hardware e facilitar o uso, mas não é muito flexível. Não pode ter erros sob pena de derrubar tudo.

## Exemplos

O Linux é monolítico, o [Minix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX) é *microkernel* e o Windows e o OSX são [híbridos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_kernel). Obviamente na prática é possível obter mais ou menos as mesmas características em qualquer forma. O jeito de fazer e os cuidados necessários em cada um é que pode mudar. Algumas pessoas consideram o Linux como híbrido já que apesar dele ser monolítico ele possui módulos externos de *kernel*.

Muitas vezes é difícil definir o que é um ou outro. De uma certa forma todos mais usados acabam sendo híbridos de alguma forma.

## Diferenças

É possível resolver as dificuldades de cada um com técnicas específicas. Não há uma clara vantagem de um sobre o outro e [há enormes debates sobre isto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanenbaum%E2%80%93Torvalds_debate). Ninguém provou inequivocamente qual é melhor, mas pelo que vemos os sistemas operacionais mais usados para aplicações em geral são híbridos, em menor ou maior grau. Aplicações específicas podem se beneficiar mais de um tipo ou outro.

Um exemplo que diferencia um do outro é a *filesystem*. Em um *microkernel* normalmente este é um componente isolado, já no monolítico ele faz parte do *kernel*. *Drivers* são outros exemplos, se eles serão executados dentro do *kernel* ou fora depende da filosofia do *kernel*.

Esta separação depende da filosofia adotada pelo produto. Independe de onde vai rodar, ainda que obviamente o local de uso pode afetar a sua filosofia. Há sistemas operacionais com núcleos completos, que até GUI está no *kernel*, e cabem em um disquete.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Na prática, depende mais da aplicação.

Se você vai trabalhar com um PC Desktop, vale à pena contar com todos os recursos de um kernel completo ou mesmo considerar o suporte a diversos sistemas diferentes para a sua aplicação e nesse caso o suporte a um kernel completo é recomendado, já que dificilmente as pessoas usam micro kernel em seus PCs.

Se você vai criar um projeto embarcado, onde você vai garantir o hardware e o software... Seu trabalho vai ser o de otimizar a solução para a sua aplicação e então passa a ser relevante e o kernel menor, que poderá ter menos overhead, menor custo e os controladores/processadores que rodam esse tipo de solução costumam consumir menos energia, o que acaba ajudando projetos que usam bateria (se todos os recursos que ele oferece te atenderem bem).

Geralmente, se você tiver o poder de fogo para viver com um kernel completo, você vai acabar usando ele porque a flexibilidade e suporte a outras soluções que isso oferece é bastante vantajoso.